# I need to update my iOS app in background after every 30 mins... how to do it?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to update my location after every 30 mins in background, with the help of background modes=location key i am able to sync with server but apple rejected it.
Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Background Fetch](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/). But you won't be able to make 100% sure that it will be executed at the exact time you want it or if it will be executed at all.
Using Background Modes to trick iOS to keep your app running with no feature actually using it will have your app rejected by Apple every time.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is already in your question - Using Background Modes to trick iOS to keep your app running with no feature actually using it will have your app rejected by Apple every time.

Please provide more details about your task that I could provide another decision for your problem.